# W3C validation giving errors on AJAX page

Tags: php, ajax, w3c-validation

Works great, but get five errors from W3C validation.  Tried the sugestions, but no help.   Issues are;

No Character Encoding Found! Falling back to UTF-8.

Unable to Determine Parse Mode!

No DOCTYPE found, and unknown root element. Aborting validation.

No Character encoding declared at document level.

errors are (does not make sense)

no document type declaration; will parse without validation.

NET-enabling start-tag requires SHORTTAG YES

character data is not allowed here

end tag for element "B" which is not open

document type does not allow element "B" here

My main page;

```
function updatedb() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { 
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","https://nextpage.com/userupdate.php?q=" + userID + "&r=" + (medeno[index][0]) + "&s=" + index, true);
xmlhttp.send();}
```

PHP AJAX Page

```
//Get values
$userID=$_GET['q'];
$secc=$_GET['r'];
$index=$_GET['s'];

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "medeno_user", "password", "medeno_users");




//Update database 1 case per video course
switch ($index) {
    case 1: $stmt1=$mysqli->prepare('UPDATE users set videoSec1=? WHERE userID=?'); break;
    case 2: $stmt1=$mysqli->prepare('UPDATE users set videoSec2=? WHERE userID=?'); break;
    case 3: $stmt1=$mysqli->prepare('UPDATE users set videoSec3=? WHERE userID=?'); break;
    case 4: $stmt1=$mysqli->prepare('UPDATE users set videoSec4=? WHERE userID=?'); break;
    case 5: $stmt1=$mysqli->prepare('UPDATE users set videoSec5=? WHERE userID=?'); break;
    case 6: $stmt1=$mysqli->prepare('UPDATE users set videoSec6=? WHERE userID=?'); break;
    case 7: $stmt1=$mysqli->prepare('UPDATE users set videoSec7=? WHERE userID=?'); break;
    case 8: $stmt1=$mysqli->prepare('UPDATE users set videoSec8=? WHERE userID=?'); break;}


$stmt1->bind_param('ii',$secc,$userID);
$stmt1->execute();
$stmt1->close(); 
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

I am a beginner.  Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to validate an Ajax response in the first place? That shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: OK, thanks!  I was trying to validate every page.  Makes sense.